# Reusing the previous back buffer on WM_PAINT

Tags: winapi, opengl

If the content of the last frame isn't changed on receiving WM_PAINT, is it possible to simply direct the operating system to redraw the window using the old back buffer instead of redrawing the whole scene again to the new back buffer and swapping it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no such "backbuffer". And when drawing occurs you don't know what areas may be covered by other windows. The clipping area isn't a real good indicator.

The only thing you know is that such areas need to be redrawn. Each window cares about its own client area. If you want to buffer something, you have to do it on your own.

The reason is simple: Imagine you have hundreds of windows. To hold a buffer for each window is inefficient, when just a view on the top are visible. So the Windows makers decide not to store any windows content and just notify windows on the top to redraw themselves.

OK. Since we have a DWM (Dynamic Window Manager) things changed a lot. But the principle is still: You are responsible to draw. If you want to buffer something, you have to do it on your own.